# Direct standardisation with missing values on ages

Tags: missing-data, standardization

I am aiming to perform a direct standardisation to calculate the prevalence rate of a certain condition in an area. What I did was merge different routinely collected health data to be able to detect all individuals affected by the condition in the area of interest. After doing so I came up with a final sample of ~ 6,000 cases (in a population of 4 million approx). I then calculated the prevalence rate (x 100,000) and relative CI using Byar's method.

As this data refers to a single region, I would like to standardise the data using the direct standardisation method and the European population as a reference.

However, I realised that for 92 individuals I do not information on the year of birth. Therefore, the calculation of the standardised rate would be biased. Although this is a very small proportion I still think that this matters, especially when calculating the standardised prevalence rates.

Multiple imputation here is not an option as I have very few variables I could use as predictors. Also, all missing values come from the same data source (I used four different data sources and only one presented this issue), so missing would not be at random.

What options do I have?

I was thinking to replace the missing values with the mean (or median) age value of the corresponding sex/district category. Practically speaking I would calculate the mean (or median) age for each group, defined by age and district of residence. For those missing, I would replace the missing value with the corresponding mean value. However, I am not sure whether this is technically sound in this case.

What do you think? A reference could be a great help!

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking about the same problem at a different level (data with age, sex, and race; one or more of those values may be missing).  I have come to a different conclusion than maybe you have.  In my view, you would be biasing your standardized rate by *not* including the 92 individuals, and the proper population fraction to assign to their "within missing age group" rate is.... 1, the proportion of persons with *any* age in the standardized population.  I think standardized rates appear to systematically exclude cases with missing values for the standardization classes.  If so, this systematically understates the "true" adjusted death rate.